# Nodes don't appear in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I wrote this code

```
var loadZones = [];
var loadSites = [];

for (var i=0; i<zones.zone.length; i++){
      loadZones[i] = { data: { id: zones.zone[i].id}, position: { x: (i+1)*100, 
     y: (i+1)*100 } };
    }
var cyt = window.cyt = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cyt'),
    });

for (var j=0; j<zones.zone.length; j++)
  cyt.add(loadZones[j]);
}
```

Zones is JSON file I uploaded here: https://github.com/bartequ/sk/edit/master/zone.json
I originally have zones in table in code. The problem is I loaded nodes properly, checked in console cyt._private.elements and there are 7 elements as many as in loadZones table, and despite this I don't see nodes on the screen.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that you forgot to call:

```
var layout = cyt.layout({
   name: 'whateverLayoutYouWant'    // null/grid/concentric/circle/...
});
layout.run();                       // dont forget to run the layout
```

If you did, here is the link to the [cytoscape.js documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.layout)